# how to create an hyperlink field programatically in a gridview, its setting 2 links

Tags: c#, asp.net

The code below, when I check the url rendered in the table is showing me something like

```
http://mysite1, http://mysite1
```

so its duplicated, I am not sure what I am doing wrong

```
 HyperLinkField biPowerLink = new HyperLinkField();
            biPowerLink.DataNavigateUrlFields = new string[] { "Link" };
            biPowerLink.HeaderText = "Link";
            biPowerLink.Text = @"<img src='" + ResolveUrl("/_layouts/15/xx/xx/Images/iclient.gif") + "' /> ";
            linkedJobsGrid.Columns.Add(biPowerLink);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var firstCell = e.Row.Cells[0];
 firstCell.Controls.Clear();
 firstCell.Controls.Add(new HyperLink { "URL", "URL"});
```

Comment: I am creating a gridview entirely by code, this is not useful